# In excel 365 how to subtract values sequentially but skip empty cells

Tags: excel, formula, cell, subtraction

Not sure how to word this exactly.  We have a spreadsheet to keep track of pump runtimes.

[image: snipped screenie]

We want to subtract the run times in column `B` and output to Column `C` so for instance `B4-B5` would output .3 to `C4`.  I don't have a problem with basic formula `=B4-B5` in `C4` and so on down the column. However when I get to `B8` I want `B7` to subtract `B10` and skip the `B8` and `B9`. The reason is that the 25th and 26th was a weekend so values weren't recorded. (these sheets are printed, recorded on location and then brought back to the plant at the end of the month) so what if possible would be a formula I can use?

after using the formula this is what happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bundr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula in C4 and drag down

```
=IF(B4<>0,B4-INDEX(B5:$B$33,MATCH(TRUE,B5:$B$33<>0,0)),0)
```

It's checking the cells below for the first non-zero and returning the difference to that value. The key principle here is in the range `B5:$B$33`. The dollar signs ensure that when you drag the formula down the end of the range you're checking stays at B33, whereas B5 will become B6, B7, etc.

Comment: holy crap batman that works!  I'm trying to follow the formula and I can't figure out HOW it works.  I'm only good with basic excel functions but i've been spending hours trying to make this work.  No where even close to what you have.  Thanks a million!

Comment: ok it works until you get to the bottom and in c32 it shows #n/a

Comment: not sure how to post a new screenie as I don't see any links to post image, so i edited original post and added second screenie

Answer (score 1):

If the column B entries are stricly non-increasing, as per your example, in `C4`:

`=IF(B4,B4-XLOOKUP(9^9,B5:B$33,B5:B$33,B4,-1),0)`

and copied down.

Comment: Thank you that worked.